# Redirect HTTPS+IP Address to Domain Name

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt

So my `example.com` configuration file successfully redirect the following URL to `https://example.com/` ...

- `http://1.2.3.4`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

... but not `https://1.2.3.4`. My question is, how do I redirect `https://1.2.3.4` to `https://example.com`?

I have not make any changes to `default` configuration file. Here is my `example.com` configuration file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com 1.2.3.4;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  server_name www.example.com 1.2.3.4;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  server_name example.com;

  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  root /var/www/example.com/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Looks fine except, your second `server` block is only listening on IPv4 while the other two are listening on both IPv4 and IPv6. Obviously the browser will generate a certificate warning as `1.2.3.4` is not a domain name.

Comment: So on second server block, I should remove:

`listen 443 ssl;`

and add

`listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
listen 443 ssl;` ?

Comment: Unless you install an SSL certificate for your IP address, you cannot get a redirect.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen so um, can I do it? Do I need to add `-d 1.2.3.4` argument inside `sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com` when initializing `certbot`?

Comment: You cannot use Letsencrypt to get certificates for IP addresses. I don't know if any certificate provider issues certificates for IP addresses.

Comment: Some must do, as e.g. https://1.1.1.1/ has one.

Comment: It's best practice to _not_ redirect visitors to your IP address, but instead to serve them an error page. Indeed, this is what the default configuration does, and why it should not be used as your own web site's configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not sure I understood what you're saying. I wanted to redirect my IP address to my domain name, not to redirect visitor to my IP address.

Comment: @EsaJokinen while I do wonder how 1.1.1.1 got SSL for that IP, I don't want to do so. I just wanted to redirect visitor from IP to domain.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen understood. If so, is there any way for me to redirect visitor who enters `https://1.2.3.4` to `https://example.com`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was not well worded. I mean that you should not redirect people who visit your IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton alright understood. So what's the best ethics in handling visitors entering my IP address into URL bar? What do I show them?